# Hiding cursor in Text component in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse RCP application there are a few buttons & few input boxes & this below Text component. My problem is as soon as I press one of the buttons a cursor starts blinking in the below test component. Can you please let me know how to solve this.

I tried:

1. setting focus to false for Text.
2. `SWT.READ_ONLY` for Text .
3. Code:

   ```
   Cursor cursor = new Cursor(parent.getDisplay(), SWT.CURSOR_NO);
   protocolFilterDescription.setCursor(cursor);
   ```

Nothing seems to get rid of this unnecessary cursor.

```
protocolFilterDescription = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE | SWT.READ_ONLY  );
FormData protocolFilterDescriptionLData = new FormData();
protocolFilterDescriptionLData.left = new FormAttachment(0, 1000, 650);
protocolFilterDescriptionLData.top = new FormAttachment(0, 1000, 290);
protocolFilterDescriptionLData.width = 450;
protocolFilterDescriptionLData.height = 12;
protocolFilterDescription.setLayoutData(protocolFilterDescriptionLData);
protocolFilterDescription.setForeground(new Color(parent.getDisplay(),
  204, 153, 0));
protocolFilterDescription.setBackground(Display.getCurrent()
  .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
protocolFilterDescription.setFont(new Font(parent.getDisplay(),"Verdana",
  6, 1));
protocolFilterDescription
  .setText("captured");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the focus of some other SWT component to `true` to remove the focus from the Text component.

You'll probably have to do this in an ActionListener.

Comment: I tried setFocus method on other components but still the cursor blinks in the input box

Comment: @user508435: Based on your other comments, why are you using Text components at all?  If you just want to display text, you can setEditable to false.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert for the response. Actually I am not seeing any cursor in the above posted code as I have changed it to Label. After making it a label now the cursor appears in input box (an another Text component where user inputs text). I tried making this input box setEditable to false but still the cursor is seen. Do you see an easlier way apart from this solution :http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/%7Echeckout%7E/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet242.java

Comment: I have 2 buttons & have set focus for both of them using setFocus(); but no use cursor still blinks in the input box. Thanks

Comment: System.out.println(button.setFocus()); gives me 'false' that means the button control was unable to get focus. but why ?

Comment: Anyways I am using inputBox.setEnabled(false); to hide the cursor. And make it true once I need it.This is fine for time being. Thanks again Gilbert

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely remove the cursor from the Text control (which implies inability to perform a selection there, etc), try calling setEnabled(false) on it.

Also, such requirement suggests that you maybe don't need Text component at all, and could use Label instead.

Comment: changing it to a Label works fine but the cursor now starts blinking in a input box after pressing a button. Is it possible to completely remove the cursor from all the children in the control?

Comment: I have 4 such input boxes. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a better way to hide than this :http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/%7Echeckout%7E/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet242.java